# Execute JMeter If controller only for the first true condition

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I have a Web socket Single Read sampler as a child of While Controller. This sampler loops for a certain (dynamic) number of times based on other input conditions. I have to extract a value from one of these responses and I have designed the test plan looks like this:

```
Thread Group
    \_ .. other components
    \_ While controller
        \_ Web socket single read sampler
            \_ Regular expression extractor to save entire response body
        \_ If controller (condition: occurrence of specific text in response body)
            \_ Dummy sampler (pass saved response body)
                \_ Regular expression extractor to save required value 
    \_ .. other components
```

Now, the problem is the condition used in the If controller is not unique. So, the required value gets overwritten to the last occurrence of the condition. Is there a way to save the response body only during the first occurrence of the condition?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [__isVarDefined()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__isVarDefined) function to the If Controller's condition, this way the [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) will be executed only if the variable set by its child Regular Expression Extractor doesn't exist:

[image]

---

If you just want to exit the while loop after the first occurrence of the data you're looking for - add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler after the Dummy Sampler and configure it to break the current loop:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! My problem was resolved by using the isVarDefined() function. I could not use Flow Control Action for my scenario as I have to let the while loop run till all messages are received.